# Should I use multiple cursors?

Tags: python, firebird, connection, cursors

I'm trying to develop a piece of software (Python 3 - Tkinter) to work with 2 firebird databases. Database "A" is of critical importance, so my program is only allowed to perform select statements on it. Database "B" is populated directly from my program, so full access is granted.

I have created multiple python classes to hold various windows (one class per window) , and inside every class I need to 1) perform SELECT statements on database A , 2) perform SELECT/INSERT/INSERT OR UPDATE statements on database B.

What I am wondering is how should I organize connection objects and cursors. I think I should open connections in main app, but I don't know whether to:

1. create only one cursor for each connection and use those cursors for every statement throughout the different classes:

   ```
   conA=fdb.connect(database A)
   conA.begin(fdb.ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_RO)
   cursorA=conA.cursor()

   conB=fdb.connect(database B)
   cursorB=conB.cursor()

   Class example1():
       cursorA.execute("SELECT ......")
       cursorB.execute("SELECT.......")
       cursorB.execute("INSERT INTO...")
   Class example2():
       cursorA.execute("SELECT ......")
       cursorB.execute("SELECT.......")
       cursorB.execute("INSERT INTO...")
   ```
2. Create multiple cursors, one for each statement, directly inside each class:

   ```
   conA=fdb.connect(database A)
   conA.begin(fdb.ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_RO)

   conB=fdb.connect(database B)

   Class example1():
       cursorA1=conA.cursor()
       cursorA1.execute("SELECT ......")

       cursorB1=conB.cursor()
       cursorB2=conB.cursor()
       cursorB1.execute("SELECT.......")
       cursorB2.execute("INSERT INTO...")
   Class example2():
       cursorA2=conA.cursor()
       cursorA2.execute("SELECT ......")

       cursorB3=conB.cursor()
       cursorB4=conB.cursor()
       cursorB3.execute("SELECT.......")
       cursorB4.execute("INSERT INTO...")
   ```
3. Open and close whole connections (and cursors) inside each class, every time that connection is needed:

   ```
   Class example1():
       conA=fdb.connect(database A)
       conA.begin(fdb.ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_RO)
       cursorA=conA.cursor()
       cursorA.execute("SELECT ......")
       conA.close()

       conB=fdb.connect(database B)
       cursorB=conB.cursor()
       cursorB.execute("SELECT ......")
       cursorB.execute("INSERT ......")
       conB.close()
   ```

   (the same for other classes)

So, is any of these options appropriate?

Comment: what you should really think about is management of transactions. All cursors exists within transactions scopes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Comment: Thanks Arioch. I have been reading about transaction management in FDB package documentation. I understand that transactions need not to be explicit, so I went with that approach since I am very new to programming. I went ahead and read the documentation again, and I think I figured it out...if I commit after every statement, even SELECT statements, current transaction is ended and another transaction is initiated at the next EXECUTE. So, I think approach number one should be correct(adding commit to every statement). Am I right?

Comment: Well, from my experience with Delphi programming (it was long ago, but still) you do have to care about transactions. Because that is the logical units of your program workflow. Implicit transactions might hurt performance (like too small too frequent transactions, or opposite, too long never ending transactions causing resource leaks). You may have several transactions in your application. For example one of patterns is that every window/form has its own transaction. There are different ideas how to organize it. But the thing is, if you understand what are logical steps in your workflow

Comment: ....then you can do explicit transactions. If you don't - then you don't. For small simplistic apps you can go without transactions, but as your program would develop to at least medium levels - you might find yourself in the no-structure chaos, without understanding what and why your program even does. Maybe you have to commit transaction after copying 10K rows of data from dbA to dbB or sooner, or later. It is not "how many statements", it is "when workflow logic asks for it"

Comment: One of patterns for example was to make two database transactions (and two connections if library does not know, how to keep two transactions within one connection): a read-only READ_COMMITED transactions that lives for tens minutes or even hours, and short read-write SNAPSHOT transactions for data changes, that works in short bursts, typically less than a second. This approach has its gotchas (temporary BLOB leaks) but it has its uses too. There is no silver bullet.

Comment: Another thing to learn is prepared queries with parameters. There is little reason to make same query as new text and new cursor, if only few variable change. Better to it with parameters, and "prepare" it (within transaction), then you can re-run it after changing parameter values much faster and easier for server.

Comment: Thank you very much Arioch! Your explanation has been very helpful. Now that I think about it, it makes sense to learn about explicit transactions BECAUSE I'm such a begginer. Maybe it will help me get a better picture on how things actually work. As for parametrized prepared queries, that's exactly what I'm doing.